# Use source file from CMake ExternalProject as dependency of target

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have an external project that provides source files that I want to use to build an executable.  I currently have something like the below:

```
ExternalProject(myproj)

add_executable(myexecutable source.c) # source.c is provided by myproj
add_depedencies(myexecutable myproj)
```

It errors and complains that it can't find source.c because it hasn't downloaded the external project yet.  Is there a way to tell CMake that source.c comes from the external project?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Using [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) I can tell CMake to get the external project first.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT source.c DEPENDS myproj COMMAND "")
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/59794921/1203241

```
set_source_files_properties(source.c PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```